# Create a gradient on border in Microsoft Expression Blend?

Tags: expression-blend

I am new to Microsoft Expression blend, and would like to create a border with Gradient dark from inside and light outside with same color; kindly help me out.

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447014/setting-borderbrush-to-lineargradientbrush-in-wpf

Comment: i want the same "OuterGlowBitmapEffect" as per in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.media.effects.outerglowbitmapeffect(v=vs.90).aspx .